# Is this the correct object to lock on for thread safety?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

The code below is going to be called from a website so having a static dictionary object in a non static class needs to be threadsafe.  Basically the purpose of the code is to encapsulate logic and to maintain the life-time of the perfmon counter(s), which are stored in an instance of CounterContainer.  The constructor is called passing in instanceName.  The constructor needs to check to see if a CounterContainer for that instanceName has been defined and stored in the dictionary.  If so, it can (and must) use that instance.  If not it creates an instance of the CounterContainer, stores it in the dictionary and then uses that instance.  The instance of the CounterContainer to be used is stored in a non static member so is thread safe from that point on.

As the only place that that the static dictionary is used is within the constructor it feels to me that it will be safe to lock on the dictionary for the duration that it will be accessed?  Is this going to cause any unforeseen issues later on with anything like blocking / deadlocks?   I can't see anything, but haven't really had the need to consider this sort of thing too much in the past.

I have also considered **lock(this):** but I don't think that would work as it would only lock the instance of PerformanceCounters being created, and not the underlying static dictionary (so would not be threadsafe).

```
namespace ToolKit
{
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public class PerformanceCounters : IPerformanceCounters
    {
        private static Dictionary<string, CounterContainer> _containers = new Dictionary<string, CounterContainer>();
        private CounterContainer _instanceContainer;

        public PerformanceCounters(string instanceName)
        {
            if (instanceName == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("instanceName");
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(instanceName)) throw new ArgumentException("instanceName");

            // Is this the best item to lock on?
            lock (_containers)
            {

                if (_containers.ContainsKey(instanceName))
                {
                    _instanceContainer = _containers[instanceName];
                    return;
                }

                _instanceContainer = new CounterContainer(instanceName);
                _containers.Add(instanceName, _instanceContainer);
            }
        }
        public void Start()
        {
            _instanceContainer.AvgSearchDuration.Start();
        }

        public void FinishAndLog()
        {
            _instanceContainer.SearchesExecuted.Increment();
            _instanceContainer.SearchesPerSecond.Increment();
            _instanceContainer.AvgSearchDuration.Increment();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using the ConcurrentDictionary class? Then you wouldn't have to worry about it - Also possible duplicate to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440957/c-concurrency-locking-and-dictionary-objects

Comment: @BrokenGlass: Sorry I missed that, yes they are pretty much identical situations.  Hadn't heard about the ConcurrentDictionary class until it was raised as response to this too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me quite common to have an explicit object instance that is used exclusively for locking.

```
private readonly object containerLock = new object();
...
lock (containerLock) {
 ...
}
```

Another tip: If you are working against .NET 4, consider using `ConcurrentDictionary`.

Comment: But +1 for the reference to ConcurrentDictionary as the ability to GetOrAdd(...) passing in a function to do the creation looks to be exactly what I want to do.  @flq:  Thanks for that, it is worth building on what @x0n has said, using the object in that way is the same as "this" as both are instance based. If you made object static then it's exactly like my supplied code but I'm locking on the exact object I'm using.

Answer (score 5):

Not to disagree with the suggestion that ConcurrentDictionary be used, but to answer more generally:

1. The best locking solution is one that doesn't lock at all. Sometimes it's not very difficult to make something concurrent without locking. Next best is having fine-grained locks. However, coarse-grained locks are much easier to reason about, and hence to be confident in their correctness. Unless you've got a well-tested lock-free class of appropriate purpose to hand, start with coarse-grain locks (locks that block a whole bunch of operations with the same lock) and then move to finer-grained either because there is a logical deadlock (you can see that two unrelated operations are likely to block each other) or as an optimisation if needed.
2. Never lock on `this` because something external to your that code could lock on the object and you can easily get a deadlock or at least lock contention that can only be found by looking at both the code internal to the class, and the calling code (and the person writing one may not have access to the other). For similar reasons, never lock on a `Type`.
3. For similar reasons, only ever lock on a private member. That way only code internal to the class can lock on it, and the possibility of lock contention is restricted to that place.
4. Avoid use of `partial` with such code, and if you do use `partial`, try to keep all locks on an object in the same place. No technical reason here, but it does help when you need to think about all the potential places a lock could be taken.
5. Never lock on a value type (integer type, struct, etc.). Doing so will box the value to a new object and lock on this. Then when some other code tries to get the lock it will box to yet another object and lock on that. Essentially there is no lock at all (barring the theoretical optimisation, of boxing using a flyweight pattern [which it doesn't] but would actually make things even worse).
6. Sometimes the purpose of the lock will relate to a single object that is used when the lock is used, and not used when a lock isn't used. In this case, using this object as that to lock on helps the readability of the code, in associating the lock with that object.
7. It's never wrong to have an object that exists purely for the purpose of the lock, so if you are unsure, just do that.
8. The lock object must be static if any of the objects affected are static, and may be instance otherwise. Conversely, since an instance lock is more finely-grained than a static lock, instance is better when it's applicable.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, had forgotten about the boxing that happens if you lock on a value type.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will work as _containers is static.

You might want to take a look at [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) as well so you want block the theard so much (improvement to performance)

Comment: +1 for reminding me about ReaderWriterLocks and that there is a slim version.  I'd completely forgotten about those, it's been a few years since I've had to worry about threading.  Will mark @flq as accepted answer as I'm going to use the ConcurrentDictionary he's referenced.

Comment: That's fine - I didn't know about ConcurrentDictionary before ;-). You learn sth every day...

Comment: I *highly* suspect that a `ReaderWriterLockSlim` would actually be slower than a plain old `lock` in this case.

Comment: @Brian Gideon - why? with lock() threads are block every time, even when the item is in the collection. ReaderWriterLock will only block during insertion.

Comment: @Jakub: True, but a `ReaderWriterLockSlim` is itself about 5x slower than a `lock` in servicing the lock overhead. Since the OP is holding the lock for such a short amount of time it likely will not be enough to overcome that additional overhead. Reader-writer locks work best when the number of readers significantly outnumbers the writers *and* when the lock is held for a long period of time. By the way, the old `ReaderWriterLock` has about 15x the overhead of a plain old `lock`. Do some benchmarks because your mileage may vary from mine.

Comment: @Brian: Thanks for the additional info

Comment: @Jakub - For a Dictionary, the instance methods (ContainsKey) are not guaranteed to be thread safe, only the static methods. So if the one thread is calling ContainsKey or the Indexer while another is calling Add, there could be problems. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710696/containskey-thread-safe

Answer (score 0):

Yes, _containers is theoretically ok as it is scoped the same as the dictionary instance, that is to say, it's a static (obviously - it IS the dictionary instance.)

However once thing worries about your overall design is that you say this is being hosted in a website. Each asp.net worker is a separate process so your static dictionary may be destroyed when IIS recycles the worker process due to idling or otherwise. Also, you may have more than one instance of your dictionary if you are using web gardens (multiple workers per application.)

Comment: The PERFMON counter stays alive for as long as there is at least one instance of the .NET reference alive in memory.  But even if there are two+ .NET references of it alive in memory they all still increment the single instance of the PERFMON counter.  So multiple IIS sites on the same server would work as I want.  A web farm is also fine as I'd want to measure on a server by server basis.  But thanks for questioning that.